# Como recuperar tudo depois do "?" em RewriteRule?

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Eu tenho a seguinte regra que foi criada por um outro programador e que está em funcionamento em alguns processos:

```
RewriteRule ^chk-error/(.*) chk_err.php?error=$1 [L]
```

Ela recupera tudo que vem depois de `chk-error/` e coloca dentro de `error` para ser tratado dentro do arquivo `chk_err.php`. Funciona normalmente.

Porém vou precisar usar a mesma página `chk_err.php` e a URL que ira acessar esse *path* virá com um ponto de interrogação. Assim:

```
https://www.example.com/chk-error/?errcat=5&errcd=514&id=12&in=gt5
```

Eu gostaria de adaptar para que ela possa recuperar tudo que vem depois da interrogação "?". Sem quebrar o processo anterior.

Como seria a nova *RewriteRule* com o "?" sendo opcional?

Em resumo eu queria reescrever a *RewriteRule* que esta funcionando para recuperar essa URL:

```
https://www.example.com/chk-error/errcat=5&errcd=514&id=12&in=gt5
```

Para poder recuperar esse outro padrão de URL:

```
https://www.example.com/chk-error/?errcat=5&errcd=514&id=12&in=gt5
```

Note que a diferença entre eles é somente o ponto de interrogação "?" depois de `chk-error/` .

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. `$_GET` não atende?

Comment: Oi Felipe eu melhorei a pergunta. Quando eu uso GET a variavel error vem vazia. O que está parecendo que a regex não esta pegando tudo depois de `chk-error/?`.  Mas se eu retiro a interrogação tudo funciona.

Answer (score -2):

Essa é a única regra que a URL passa? Se eu entendi direito, basta você negar o simbolo `?` na regra e tudo deve funcionar como você quer.

`RewriteRule ^chk-error/(^?.*) chk_err.php?error=$1 [L]`

Answer (score -2):

É necessário utilizar a flag **[QSA]** *(Query String Append)* para passar os parâmetros da url.

[Fonte](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)